# Apache 500 error only on ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, internal-server-error

I have a jquery ajax call that returns a 500 error.  If I type the url directly into my browser, it works fine (it is a GET request).

I'm using apache 2.2.23 with php 5.4.10.  There is nothing in the apache or php logs even with log level set to debug.  The crazy thing is, this same ajax call works on other peoples' machines.

Firebug console shows the 500 error, but the body of the response is the actual content that I expect to be returned.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? , try using firebug

Comment: Code never mistakes, we do mistakes..          check to make sure that your code doesn't contain errors

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Are you using some kind of server-side framework? Try to narrow the issue down.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox as a browser install Firebug..I hope it will help you in tracking any ajax bug/error!

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the page on all machines from the same hostname? If yes, you have to use jsonp as ajax normally doesn't work over multiple domains.

Comment: All are different developers machines, all running the same local host.

Comment: may you can give us a little piece of your code? The js would be great, and maybe even parts of the php script.